# How to get max zoom for maptype in location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On Google Maps' [JS API reference page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MaxZoomService), it says that the method `getMaxZoomAtLatLng`:

> Returns the maximum zoom level available at a particular LatLng for
>   the Satellite map type.

For some reason, the terrain maptype bottoms out at **level 15** in Calgary (for example) but the Satellite maptype can go all the way to **zoom 19**.  I have two map services running simulataneously, and I want the maps to be in sync, but they can't sync up if they can't reach the same zoom level.

So, basically **I want to know when the terrain map (or any maptype) can't cope, and trigger some special case functions.**

Is there a method, or an alternative, for getting the maximum zoom for a location for a specific map type (since the above mentioned method only works for Satellite)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one solution I've decided to go with in the meantime is to attach a `zoom-end` handler to my ArcGIS map (could easily do this with Leaflet as well) and a `maptypeid_changed` handler to the Google map.

So, for the ArcGIS map (`eMap`) I did this:

```
eMap.on('zoom-end', function (e) {
  // map zooms are synced
  gMap.setCenter(esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(e.extent.getCenter()));
  gMap.setZoom(e.level);

  // if the google map couldn't do it, reset eMap
  if (gMap.getZoom() !== e.level) {
    eMap.setZoom(gMap.getZoom());
    // runs the handler again
  }
});
```

And if the google map was set to Satellite, then changed, it also needed to trigger the same check, so I forced it to execute another zoomEnd handler:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(gMap, 'maptypeid_changed', function () { 
  // for some reason, ESRI has issues setting zoom to current zoom
  // so it has to run an initial check before calling zoomEnd
  if (gMap.getZoom() !== eMap.getZoom()) {
    eMap.setZoom(gMap.getZoom());
  }
});
```

Hope this helps someone, but really, I'm looking forward to seeing a better solution than this.  Seems like an awfully complicated approach to merely firing a function if Google's maptype can't reach a certain zoom level.